# Updating npm package of preload-js 0.6.3 but still the version inside file showing 0.4.1

Tags: node.js, preloadjs

I'm working in node environment. I have installed preload-js node modules from https://www.npmjs.com/package/preload-js. The displaying version is 0.6.3. The package.json is also showing the same version.

```
  "preload-js": "^0.6.3",
```

But inside the actual file, node_modules\preload-js\index.js. It shows as follows (version="0.4.1")

```
/*!
* @license PreloadJS
* Visit http://createjs.com/ for documentation, updates and examples.
*
* Copyright (c) 2011-2013 gskinner.com, inc.
*
* Distributed under the terms of the MIT license.
* http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.html
*
* This notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
*/
window.createjs=window.createjs||{},function(){"use strict";var a=createjs.PreloadJS=createjs.PreloadJS||{};a.version="0.4.1",a.buildDate="Thu, 12 Dec 2013 23:33:38 GMT"}
```

In http://www.createjs.com/preloadjs, Version 0.6.2 is released by November 2015.
How can I update? I have tried npm update process but no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>a.version="0.4.1" do not specify the version of "preload-js". Check the "version" field inside package.json instead.</s>

There is something wrong with preload-js installed by npm.You can build it v0.6.2 by yourself.Here is the [steps](https://github.com/CreateJS/PreloadJS/tree/0.6.2/build).

Comment: Are you sure? I don't think so. could you please refer this URL [PreloadJS v0.6.2](http://www.createjs.com/docs/preloadjs/files/preloadjs_version.js.html#l6).

Comment: Sorry,you are right. a.version specify the version of "preload-js".I build it 0.6.2 by myself and a.version is 0.6.2.You can build "preload-js" by yourself. Here is the steps [build preload-js](https://github.com/CreateJS/PreloadJS/tree/0.6.2/build).